# Groovy template - code generation

Tags: templates, groovy

I am asking for advice and opition as of the code to use with groovy templates.

All template examples on the web used a very limited logic but I simply cannot overcome that barrier and the code in my template is substantial.

Is this acceptable? What could be a better way to do this?

Thanks
Peter

The task is to generate TCL type code - specifically if then/elsif/else type contraint

```
if { [streq $pm_enrichment('a1') "'aaaa2'"] && [strlen $pm_enrichment('aaaa3')] &&\
    [strlen $pm_enrichment('aaaa4') ] } { 
     set pm_enrichment('ResultAAA') 0 
}
elseif { [streq $pm_enrichment('b1') "'bb2'"] && [strlen $pm_enrichment('bbb3')] &&\
[strlen $pm_enrichment('bbbb4') ] } { 
     set pm_enrichment('ResultBBB') 1 
}
else { [streq $pm_enrichment('c1') "'cc2'"] && [strlen $pm_enrichment('ccc3')] &&\
[strlen $pm_enrichment('cccc4') ] } { 
     set pm_enrichment('ResultCCC') 2G 
} 


//////////////////////////////////////
def dataCasesClosure= {->
    pos=0
    arrSorted = []
    mapStmt.each{arrSorted.add(it.key) }
    arrSorted = arrSorted.sort()
    outStr=''''''

arrSorted.each { i ->
    tmpStatement = statement
    tmpResultStmt = resultStmt
    list=mapStmt[i]
    resultList=mapResultStmt[i]

pos=0
int index = tmpStatement.indexOf(keyword);
while (index >=0){
    val = list[pos].replaceAll(~'"','')
    pos +=1
    tmpStatement=tmpStatement.replaceFirst( ~/#/,/${val}/)
    index = tmpStatement.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length())   ;
}

if (tmpStatement ==~/\W+$/) {
    tmpStatement=tmpStatement[0..-2]
}

pos=0
index = tmpResultStmt.indexOf(keyword);
while (index >=0){
    val = resultList[pos]
    pos +=1
    tmpResultStmt=tmpResultStmt.replaceFirst( ~/#/,/${val}/)                
    index = tmpResultStmt.indexOf(keyword, index+keyword.length())  ;
}

if (i==0) {
    outStr= "if {${tmpStatement} } { \n\t\t ${tmpResultStmt} \n  }"
} else if (i < arrSorted.size()-1  ){
    outStr += "elseif {${tmpStatement} } { \n\t\t ${tmpResultStmt} \n  }"
} else {
    outStr += "else {${tmpStatement} } { \n\t\t ${tmpResultStmt} \n  }"
}
}

outStr

} // ### dataCasesClosure

def valuesIfThenStmt= [
"statement":dataCasesClosure
]

tplIfThenStmt = '''
##############################
${statement}
'''

def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
templateResult = engine.createTemplate(tplIfThenStmt).make(valuesIfThenStmt)
println templateResult.toString()
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is all you have to generate, the template is overkill.  You could have just called the dataCasesClosure directly to get its output.

Assuming it is part of a larger template then, I think it is very reasonable to use closures to produce output for a particularly complex parts, just as you have done.  I have personally done this on an extreme scale with good results.